# git remote -v not showing remote after git fetch --all

Tags: git, git-remote, git-fetch

I'm working with a git project and I need to add a remote repository.
In the **PC1** I added the remote repo with:
`git remote add new_repo https://192.168.2.223` (this is the IP of my **PC1** within the network).
Then, in another pc (**PC2**) within the same network, I tried to fetch the *new_repo* I've just created:
`git fetch --all`.

Now in the **PC2**, if I type: `git remote -v` I can't see the *new_repo*.
What's wrong?

Comment: add remote on PC2

Comment: `git fetch` cannot "fetch" remotes. You have to manually add remotes.

Comment: In the [git-scm docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) I see that the --all option allows to fetch all remotes, so why it doesn't fetch the new remote?

oh sure... it fetches remote branches and tags... thanks for helping me ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Remotes must be configured on each local repo.

Remote configuration is not shared among repos.  In a typical setup, for example, the `origin` repo does not know itself as a remote (and may or may not not have any configured remotes); when a user clones from this central repo, the default behavior sets `origin` itself as a remote (because it's what was cloned), but even if the central repo *does* have other remotes, they are not copied.

This is almost always the desired behavior.  In cases where it is not, the problem can be addressed the same as for any other local git configuration that you might want to share: by committing a script that the developer may run to set up those configuration values you want to share.